# long running queries and new data

Tags: postgresql

I'm looking at a postgres system with tables containing 10 or 100's of millions of rows, and being fed at a rate of a few rows per second.

I need to do some processing on the rows of these tables, so I plan to run some simple select queries: select * with a where clause based on a range (each row contains a timestamp, that's what I'll work with for ranges). It may be a "closed range", with a start and an end I know are contained in the table, and I know no new data will fall into the range, or an open range : ie one of the range boundary might not be "in the table yet" and rows being fed in the table might thus fall in that range.

Since the response will itself contains millions of rows, and the processing per row can take some time (10s of ms) I'm fully aware I'll use a cursor and fetch, say, a few 1000 rows at a time. My question is:

If I run an "open range" query: will I only get the result as it was when I started the query, or will new rows being inserted in the table that fall in the range while I run my fetch show up ?

(I tend to think that no I won't see new rows, but I'd like a confirmation...)

Comment: I tried it playing with 3 transaction and no matter when I insert row if cursor transaction started earlier it does not see new rows - no matter when I fetch or commit the inserting transactions. but I believe it's not insured as its not monitored without serialyzable level. But you should wait for more attention to your question I would say - I never experienced concurrent transactions, but in subquery - so I'm not sure same rules appies when fetching

Comment: Thanks Vao, here is what the helpfully pointed to manual says :
Read Committed is the default isolation level in PostgreSQL. When a transaction uses this isolation level, a SELECT query (without a FOR UPDATE/SHARE clause) sees only data committed before the query began.
So I think I have my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**updated**

It should not happen under any isolation level:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/transaction-iso.html

but Postgres insures it only in **Serializable** isolation

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think when you make a query, that means you create a new transaction and it will not receive/update data from any other transaction until it commit.

So, basically "you only get the result as it was when you started the query"